# Firebase Realtime Database concurrent connections reliability

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I count the concurrent connections as follows:

```js
onValue(ref(db, '.info/connected'), snapshot => {
            
    if (snapshot.val()) {

        let con = push(ref(db, 'concurrent'), { connected: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') })

        onDisconnect(con).remove()

    }
})
```

However, when I check the database, I see connections from several days ago:

[image]

Does that mean that users have had inactive browser tabs since several days ago? Am I doing something wrong? Is the `onDisconnect()` function 100% reliable?

Answer (score 1):

*firebaser here*

Do you have security rules on the `concurrent` path that require the user to be authenticated by any chance? Because there's an open [issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/174) around that, which has been causing problems for more people recently.

Aside from that we haven't seen reliability issues in `onDisconnect` handling recently, so we'd need to see more information about the lingering connections (a stand-alone repro would be good).

Comment: No security rules on the`concurrent` path, write and read rules are set as true.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [issue](https://github.com/mdn/webextensions-examples/issues/194), it seems that if the tab is inactive for more than an hour, the token expires. If the tab is active again, Firebase client reconnects and gets a new token.

To remove the path in case of token expiration (idle tab):

```js
const onIdleTabGoOffline = (ms) => {

    let timer

    document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', () => {

        if(document.hidden){

            timer = setTimeout(() => goOffline(db), ms)

        }
        else{

            clearTimeout(timer)

            goOnline(db)

        }

    })

}
```

Finally:

```js
onValue(ref(db, '.info/connected'), snapshot => {
    
    if (snapshot.val()) {

        let con = push(ref(db, 'concurrent'), { connected: moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm') })

        onDisconnect(con).remove()

        onIdleTabGoOffline(59 * 60 * 1000)

    }
})
```